# Meteo HTTP call: can't access data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, object, meteor

I'm experiencing a strange problem with meteor. I'm trying to make HTTP call an use the data in a React-Component. But I can't access the returned data. 
on the server:

```
'get': function get() {

    try {
      const data = Meteor.http.get('url', {
        params: {
            "api_key": "key",
            "attribute": "attribute"
        }
      }
      return data.data;

    } catch (exception) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('500', exception);
    }
},
```

on the client: i've set up a container using `withTracker()` so that i can access the http response as props in my react component.

```
export default withTracker(() => {
    var data = [];
    Meteor.call('get', function(error, success) { 
        if (error) { 
            console.log('error', error.reason); 
        } 
        if (success) { 
            data.push(success);
            console.log('success', success); 
        } 
    });

    return {
        data,
    };
})(Component);
```

I've tried all possible combination. Using `arrays` and `objects`, but none of them worked out. When using `console.log(data)`, I get some data on the client. But using `console.log(data[0])` return `undefined`.

I've also tried returning an object from the server `'get'` method. An using js `Object.assign`. But when calling `console.log(data.name)` for example, I get `undefined` on the client.

Maybe I'm not solving it the right way, but I don't understand why this is always returning `undefined` when I tried to access the object's data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by calling putting `Meteor.call` in a `component method`, and passing another `component method` in the `callback` because `Meteor.call` does not support `promises` or `async / await`. [reference](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteo-http-call-cant-access-data/40993/2)